# Sqlite for all mobile?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite with android 2.1 . Now, i was wondering if sqlite works with any mobile with android? , maybe my question is kind of silly, but I just want to be sure that I wont have problems once i finish my app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its safe to assume that every device running Android can handle sqlite ;) It has been there since API level 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sqlite is simplest database best supported with all the Android Devices. You don't need to worry about whether it is going to support or not.